# What if a lecturer has to use the bathroom while on stage?

Tags: teaching, etiquette

If a student has to use the bathroom, s/he may simply politely and quietly excuse him/herself for a few minutes.

**But is there any established etiquette for what an instructor is to do when nature suddenly calls?**  Let's say this is a typical classroom lecture of about 90 minutes, meaning a student body of about 80-90 and no scheduled breaks.

Oh, also, let's assume that there's no real illness or other crippling circumstance that forces the instructor to leave; just a good old-fashioned porcelain inspection, resulting from consuming just a bit much V8 an hour earlier (seriously, that strawberry-banana V-Fusion is *addictive*).

Comment: Give the students an exercise. "Discuss this problem with the person sitting next to you. I'll be back in five minutes."

Comment: Part of the usual etiquette is taking off the microphone, if any.

Comment: Restroom *before* class.  In 20 years of teaching, I've never had to leave a class for the restroom.  (I did once become sufficiently ill to need an ambulance.  I said, "Ladies and gentlemen, please excuse me; I am ill.  Class is dismissed," and fled out the door.)

Comment: Whatever you do, do NOT wait till the last second. Once I did and had to sprint out of the classroom before I could say "I'll be back". Of course, everyone understood what was up because I got covered in sweat and had a roll of "emergency paper" in my hand while running. It could have ended even worse...

Comment: I teach a 3.5 hour night class some terms. For a marathon like that you call breaks. The students need them every bit as much as you do. And you use the facilities during the breaks just like you use them before a normal class.

Comment: If you can't hold it in for just 90 minutes then you might consider going to see your doctor. Nature does not usually "suddenly call" - you know when you ate, and you know when you drank, and you know where the restroom is before you step foot into the lecture hall. Unless you avoided going for a wee for several hours before the lecture despite feeling that you needed to, and subsequently drank lots of water, you _should_ be fine for 90 minutes..

Comment: I agree with @dmckee. Even if there is no scheduled break, I don't see why you could not make an unscheduled break (a very short one). Staying focused for 90 minutes is nigh-impossible even without bathroom emergencies, and making a short break at the right moment is good for everyone.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You shouldn't forget that some people suffer from intestinal diseases, as Crohn's Disease or Ulcerative Colitis. It is not a matter of "see your doctor". Maybe the person already did, and it now has a diagnosis and a treatment, but not a cure. So, yes, nature usually "suddenly call" some people. It is not reasonable that those people cannot give a lecture just because that need for a break _might_ happen.

Comment: @RafaelEyng: Yes, precisely. I'm saying, if someone thinks this is "normal" then they should go see their doctor, because they may have one of those diseases.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Many people have to go to the restrooms more frequently because they have to take drugs like diuretics because they suffer from high-blood pressure, and sometimes they have no other options (e.g. because of allergies). Thus, don't be too quick on drawing conclusions on when someone _should_ be fine.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: You're not listening to me. I'm _saying_, if you find you can't get through a 90 minute lecture, _and you don't already have a known medical reason for it_, you need to see a doctor because _you may have a medical reason that needs diagnosis_. I'm not "drawing conclusions" on anyone. Obviously if you already have special medical needs then that doesn't apply.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: :)

Comment: It is nothing to be ashamed about.  Everybody poops.  Give your students a break and take care of your biological needs.  http://www.amazon.com/Everyone-Turtleback-Library-Binding-Edition/dp/0613685725

Comment: "Intermission" back in 10 minutes...

Comment: Whatever you do, just don't do it while on stage.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think the point was not that it was a regular occurrence, but rather, given the context in the question, because you did something dumb and ate or drank something you probably shouldn't have eaten or drank in that quantity. Not the brightest idea in general, especially before going on stage for whatever reason, but also not a medical condition, just a temporary lack of self-control. :p

Comment: @neminem: Well either see a stomach doctor or someone who can help you with basic life organisation skills I suppose, yeah ;)

Comment: Just to go along with a posted answer, you could give a copy of your lecture notes to a TA prior to the lecture so they're prepared to teach any part that you're unable to cover. If you think you are so ill as to necessitate frequent breaks, though, consider staying home and maybe visit an acute care clinic.

Comment: Take a small break and I'll be back in 5 minutes - and you take off the microphone

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Ideally, you use the bathroom before lecturing which should prevent you from needing the bathroom during the lecuture. In cases where you are unwell, I find it best to let the class know ahead of time to tell them you are unwell and might need to suddenly excuse yourself, but that you will be back.

Regardless of if you have told the students in advance, if you must excuse yourself, do it politely and tell them you will be back in a few moments.

Comment: I'm agreeing.  There's really nothing too specific about this compared to any other job.  If you're unable to do a job (regardless of how public your performance is), sometimes you just need to explain that you're excusing yourself, set any expectations that are required (like when you estimate that you'll be back), and then do whatever you have to do.  People understand bathroom needs, medical needs, etc.  It might be a less polished performance, and some people might be less forgiving of "imperfection" than others, but sometimes we imperfect people have to just do the best that we can.

Answer (score 6):

for my own classes, I prepare with anticipation:
1) an exercise that students could complete while I am away from the Classroom or 
2) show an instructional video and ask students to fill a questionnaire at the end to evaluate their comprehension of the presentation.

If there is no need to use these resources, then I just left them as assignment for next class.

Ideally, in our 21st century, every teacher should be able to record their own classes in video.  In case of an unexpected emergency, students watch this lesson's recording, at least in that day.

Answer (score 4):

A plausible reason is if the instructor becomes ill, and this manifests partway through a lecture.

In this case, the only thing they can do is politely explain that they are unwell.

If a teaching assistant is on hand, they may be able to take over the lecture. If not, they may choose to invite the students to use the room and time remaining for self instruction. At the university level, students should, as a group, be able to fill in the blanks for a missed half lecture.

In either case, a follow up email indicating that the next class either will or will not precede as scheduled is probably a good idea. This may include information on a time, or times, when the professor will be available to provide clarification on the subjects that were unexpectedly omitted. It should probably not include the details of the illness, unless it is sufficiently serious as to merit inclusion to explain why the professor is changing mid-semester.